# How to make the beginning of x axis and y axis the same on ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis, x-axis

let's say I have this df and I created a plot using ggplot

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:10,
                y = -10,1)

df

library(ggplot2)


ggplot(df)+aes(x=x,y=y)+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:10,limits=c(0,10))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = -10:0,limits=c(-10,0) )
```

I would like that the labels 0 (x axis) and -10 (y axis) are on the intersection of x axis and y axis

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is add `expand = c(0,0)` to the `scale_x/y_continuous` - here it would be:

```
ggplot(df) + aes(x = x, y = y)+
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = 0:10, limits=c(0,10)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = -10:0, limits=c(-10,0))
```

[image]